# Nginx, wrong site served

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx

I have my site on the IP 1.2.3.4

On my domain provider I have both onesite.com and anothersite.com pointing to 1.2.3.4

With Nginx, I have two sites configured:

```
server {
    listen 1.2.3.4:80;
    server_name www.oneserver.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://onserver.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 1.2.3.4:80;
    server_name onserver.com;

    location / {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8878;

    [..]
```

And:

```
server {
    listen 1.2.3.4:80;
    server_name myapp.anotherserver.com;

    location / {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/myapp.sock;

    [..]
```

When I access myapp.anotherserver.com I get redirected to oneserver.com

Any help?

Comment: Did you completely restart Nginx after modifying the configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

As `user186340` pointed out, your configuration snippet looks good and accessing `myapp.anotherserver.com` in port `80` should be served in the 3rd block you provided. If it does not work as you describe, it might be because it is not loaded.

1. Make sure all the configuration you showed here was found/loaded by nginx
2. Use `nginx -t` to validate your configuration
3. Monitor your error log when you send a [`HUP` signal](http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html#reconfiguration) to the nginx master process to spot any error message popping up
4. If you are using nginx v1.9.2+, you might wish to use [`nginx -T`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/switches.html) to dump the loaded configuration to standard output

If all the following was OK, you probably modified the showed configuration compared to the one you effectively use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Nginx chooses the default server and serves that to any request without a server explicitly defined. My workaround is to define a default server that does nothing.

```
# This just prevents Nginx picking a random default server if it doesn't know which
# server block to send a request to
server {
    # You can add 443/ssl if you need to
    listen      80 default_server; 
    server_name _;

    access_log off; log_not_found off;

    # "I'm a teapot", effectively "go away" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error
    # Code 403 (forbidden), 410 (gone) or 501 (not implemented) is probably a better choice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error
    return 418; 
}
```